# Getting the current instance of ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, restkit

I'm implementing a login system.

`LoginViewController` handles the View (duh!) for this system, `LoginSession` is a singleton that handles the authentication and storage of the current session, the authentication is made via RestKit.

```
//LoginViewController.m
- (IBAction)loginButtonPress:(id)sender {
    (...)
   [[LoginSession sharedInstance] authenticateUser:[username text] withPassword:[password text] andDomain:[domain text]];
}


//LoginSession.m
- (void) authenticateUser:(NSString *)userName withPassword:(NSString *)password andDomain:(NSString *)domain{
    (...)
     RKRequest * loginRequest = [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/login" queryParameters:loginData delegate:self];
    (...)
}
```

After this request is done, it calls the delegate:

```
//LoginSession.m
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response;
```

Which needs to call the LoginViewController back, to display an error or allow the user to access the application.

I tried instantiating the `LoginViewController` using the Storyboard, but turns out it were creating a new instance:

```
//LoginSession.m
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
    
LoginViewController *loginViewController =
(LoginViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"loginViewController"];
```

And I've even tried storing `LoginViewController's` `self` in a property on `LoginSession`:
(which gets an error)

```
//LoginSession.m
@property (strong, retain) LoginViewController *loginViewController;
```

So, what's the proper way of contacting the current active instance of the `ViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

- Delegate Pattern, being used everywhere in iOS
- Notification Pattern, e.g. NSNotificationCenter

Comment: Ok, so I can substitute the RKRequest * loginRequest = [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/login" queryParameters:loginData delegate:self]; 'self' for something so I can delegate to the LoginViewController, but what should I write instead of self?

Answer (score 0):

```
//LoginSession.h
@property (strong, retain) LoginViewController *loginViewController; 

@synthesize loginViewController;

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
loginViewController =
(LoginViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"loginViewController"];
```

Push or present loginViewController

and use the loginViewController to call delegate methods

Comment: I tried this, as I told, but it would work as if it were a new instance.

Comment: Its the initial view controller, no can push ;(

Comment: LoginSession is a singleton so you can do something like this to push or present the VC in LoginSession  -(void)pushLoginVCOnViewController:(id)anController{ UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
loginViewController =
(LoginViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"loginViewController"]; [anController.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:YES]; }